# Can I mark angular2-json-schema-form?

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

For example I have next html:

```
<div *ngFor="let integration of integrations | objKeys">
  <h4 (click)="toggleVisibleForIntegration(integration.key)" #integr>
    {{visibleForIntegration.get(integration.key) ? '▼' : '▶'}} {{integration.value.name}}
  </h4>
  <div *ngIf="visibleForIntegration.get(integration.key)">
    <div *ngFor="let scenario of integration.value.scenarios | objKeys">
      <p (click)="toggleVisibleForScenario(integration.key, scenario.key)">
        {{visibleForIntegrationScenarioWraper(integration, scenario) ? '▼' : '▶'}} {{scenario.value.name}}
      </p>
      <p>
        <app-schema-form
          #schem
          [id] = "integration.key"
          *ngIf="visibleForIntegrationScenarioWraper(integration, scenario)"
          [schema]="pojoMapWrapper(scenario)"
          [layout]="layout"
          [options]="options"
          (onSubmit)="executeScenario($event)">
        </app-schema-form>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wonder is there a way mark angular2-json-schema-form and then get her with id in component? As see from code that I posted above, I have several `<app-schema-form></app-schema-form>` and I need get selected of them in component (with data and schema), but I don't have any idea. I read about FormGroup and ViewChildren, but I don't know how to distinguish `<app-schema-form></app-schema-form>` that was selected from other.
I will appreciate for your suggestions.